# R - system commands with multiple pipe do not return stdout

Tags: r, bash, pipe, system

bash:

```
ps -aux | grep -E "^.*\b[^grep](python).*(runserver).*$" 2>/dev/null | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2
```

It's return correct result. (eg.)

```
1450
1452
```

This same code in R

```
vLog <- system('ps -aux | grep -E "^.*\b[^grep](python).*(runserver).*$" 2>/dev/null | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2', intern = TRUE)
```

return `character(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `\b` with `\\b` and also  be aware of `[^grep]` which matches any character but not of `g` or `r` or `e` or `p`.

```
vLog <- system('ps -aux | grep -E "^.*\\b[^grep](python).*(runserver).*$" 2>/dev/null | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2', intern = TRUE)
```

**Example:**

```
> system('ps -aux | grep -E "^.*\\bpython" 2>/dev/null | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2', intern = TRUE)
[1] "2519" "2526" "3285" "3291"
> system('ps -aux | grep -E "^.*\bpython" 2>/dev/null | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2', intern = TRUE)
character(0)
```